# Obtener contenido de EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, poo, aplicación-web

Que tal? Una ayuda por favor, tengo este código en el cual agrego 10 `EditText` a mi `activity`.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    EditText columna = new EditText(this);
    columna.setHint("Texto " + i);
    columna.setId(i);
    mlayout.addView(columna);
}
```

Después genero un Botón, en el cual quiero recuperar el texto de los 10 EditText, el código de mi botón es el siguiente:

```
Button btnGuardar = new Button(this);
btnGuardar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));
btnGuardar.setId(0);
btnGuardar.setText("GUARDAR");
mlayout.addView(btnGuardar);
btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new ButtonsOnClickListener(this,0));
```

Tengo una clase para el Listener de cada uno de mis botones del activity, para este caso seria...

```
class ButtonsOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context context;
    int numButton;

    public ButtonsOnClickListener(Context context, int numButton) {
        this.context = context;
        this.numButton = numButton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (numButton) {
            case 0:
                //Aqui es donde deseo obtener el contenido de mis EditText
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Alguna idea? Desde ya, gracias por su atencion.

Comment: Cual es el error, veo que aqui tienes un 1 : for(int i=0; i<10; 1++) {

Comment: Si ya me percate, pero sigo con mi pregunta, la corrección en este caso es: for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

Comment: Necesitas agregar un mismo for dentro de onclick donde generes un nuevo EditText y le pases el  id del elemento

Comment: Eso es lo que he intentado hacer, pero no lo logro...

Comment: Hay que editar siempre las preguntas con las actualizaciones para que sea más fácil la comprensión a los desarrolladores, agregué una respuesta, sauldos.

Answer (score 1):

Noto que tanto los `EditText` que creas programaticamente como el botón se encuentran dentro de la misma vista que es `mlayout`, como solución puedes obtener todos los elementos que sean `EditText` que se encuentren agregados a  `mlayout` y obtener su texto.

```
        for(int index = 0; index<((ViewGroup)v.getParent()/* Obtiene vista padre */).getChildCount(); ++index) {
            //Obtiene vista hijo.
            View viewChild = ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()/* Obtiene vista padre */).getChildAt(index);

            if(viewChild instanceof EditText) { //Es EditText?
                Log.i("EditText", "EditText texto: " + ((EditText) viewChild).getText().toString());
            }else{ //No es editText
                Log.i("Button", "No es EditText");
            }
        }
```

este sería el código completo modificado del `listener`:

```
   class ButtonsOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        Context context;
        int numButton;

        public ButtonsOnClickListener(Context context, int numButton) {
            this.context = context;
            this.numButton = numButton;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for(int index = 0; index<((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).getChildCount(); ++index) {
                View viewChild = ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).getChildAt(index);

                if(viewChild instanceof EditText) {
                    Log.i("EditText", "EditText texto: " + ((EditText) viewChild).getText().toString());
                }else{
                    Log.i("Button", "No es EditText");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Nunca he intentado algo así, pero siguiendo los requerimientos que describes una posible solución sería:

En el caso para crear los editText, se crea una lista de este Objeto para referenciarlos más adelante.

```
EditText editText ;
List<EditText> listEditText = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   

    editText = new EditText(this);
    listEditText.add(editText);
    editText.setContentDescription("id-paraRecordar"); //Un id para identificarlo
}
```

Y para recuperar los datos, se hace con ese id que se le asignó

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
  String id = editText.getContentDescription(); //Se 

 //Y para obtener el valor. Ya que se sabe cuál es el id obtendrá el valor contenido
  String text = editText.getText();

}
```

Entonces en tu `onClick` se activa el método

Nunca lo he intentado. Por cualquier cosa me cuentas y lo veo más a fondo. 
Saludos.

Comment: Este id para que lo usas? String id = editText.getContentDescription();

Comment: Para identificar el editText, es decir, para saber cuál es y trabajar con él.